# Lisp: How to set element in list of lists?

Tags: lisp, clisp

I am familiar with how to set elements in a 2D array, which can be done using the following statement.

```
(setf (aref array2D 0 0) 3)
```

However, I am not familiar how to set elements in a list of lists, such as the following input: `'((1) (2) (2) (1))`. I can't use `aref`, since it only works on arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, while [`aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm#aref) works on [`arrays`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_a.htm#array), [`elt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_elt.htm) works on [`sequences`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_s.htm#sequence) which can be:

1. an ordered collection of elements
2. a vector or a list.

```
* (setf test-list '((1) (2) (2) (1)))
((1) (2) (2) (1))
* (setf (elt test-list 2) 'hi)
HI
* test-list
((1) (2) HI (1))
```

---

You can indeed use variables in place of fixed offsets:

```
* (setf test-list '((1) (2) (2) (1)))
((1) (2) (2) (1))
* (setf offset 2)
2
* (setf (elt test-list offset) 'hi)
HI
* test-list
((1) (2) HI (1))
```

Comment: The elt method seems to work when I provide a hard-coded index; however, it does ont seem to work when I provide a variable. Is it possible to use elt with a variable?

Comment: Yes you can! I updated the answer to provide you an example.

Answer (score 1):

To *access* the nth element of a list, there are (at least) two functions: `nth` and `elt`. The order of the parameters is different, and `nth` only work on lists while `elt` works on any sequence (*i.e.* lists, vector, strings ...):

```
(nth 1 '(foo bar baz)) => BAR
(nth 1 #(foo bar baz)) => ERROR
(elt '(foo bar baz) 1) => BAR
(elt #(foo bar baz) 1) => BAR
```

Now, in general, the way to *set* a value (as opposed to simply access it) is very straightforward, and at least for built-in functions this is almost always the case: whenever you have some form `FORM` which retrieves some value from what is called a `place`, the form `(setf FORM <value>)` will set this element to the given `<value>`. This works for functions such as `car, cdr, gethash, aref, slot-value, symbol-function` and many others, and any combination of those.

In your example, you have a list of lists. So, for example, to modify the "inner integer" in say the third list:

```
* (setf test-list '((0) (1) (2) (3))) ; changed the values to have something clearer
((0) (1) (2) (3))
* (car (nth 2 test-list)) ; this accesses the integer in the second list
2
* (setf (car (nth 2 test-list)) 12) ; this modifies it. Notice the syntax
12
* test-list
((0) (1) (12) (3))
```

On a side note, you should avoid modifying literal lists (created using the quote symbol `'`). If you want to modify lists, create them at runtime using the `list` function.

EDIT:
What happens is that setf knows, by "looking" at the form you give it, how to actually find the place that you want to modify, potentially using functions in this process.

If you look at other languages, such as Python, you also have some kind of duality in the syntax used both to get and to set values. Indeed, if you have a list `L` or a dictionary `d`, then `L[index]` and `d[thing]` will get the corresponding element while `L[index] = 12` and `d[thing] = "hello"` will modify it.

However, in Python, those accessors use a special syntax, namely, the squares brackets `[]`. Other types of objects use another syntax, for example, the dot notation to access slots/attributes of an object as in `my-object.attr`. A consequence is that the following code is invalid in Python:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

>>> max(L)

3
>>> max(L) = 12

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

You have to write an *other* function, for example, `setMax(L, val)`, to change the maximum of a list. This means that you now have to functions, and no symmetry anymore.

In Common Lisp, everything is (at least syntactically) a function call. This means that you can *define* new ways to access and modify things, for any function ! As a (bad) example of what you could do:

```
* (defun my-max (list)
    (reduce #'max list))
MY-MAX
* (my-max '(1 2 3 8 4 5))
8
* (defun (setf my-max) (val list)
    (do ((cur list (cdr cur))
         (cur-max list (if (< (car cur-max) (car cur))
                               cur
                               cur-max)))
        ((endp (cdr cur)) (setf (car cur-max) val))))

(SETF MY-MAX)
* (setf test-list (list 0 4 5 2 3 8 6 3))
(0 4 5 2 3 8 6 3)
* (setf (my-max test-list) 42)
42
* test-list
(0 4 5 2 3 42 6 3)
```

This way, the syntax used to both set and get the maximum of a list is identical (`FORM` to get, `(setf FORM val)` to set), and combines automatically with every other "setter". No explicit pointers/references involved, it's just functions.